# Usage of same workspace for RTC CLI and GUI

Tags: eclipse, command-line-interface, rtc

Is it possible that we can use same workspace for both CLI and GUI for RTC scm and synchronize the results in both clients?

First I would use a folder to create a repository connection,workspace and Load it through CLI. When I launch Eclipse RTC and use the same workspace, can I get the repository connection, and workspace loaded?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that we can use same workspace for both CLI and GUI

Yes, you can reference the same:

- repo workspace
- local workspace

Any operation done in one (like the CLI) would be reflected in the second (the GUI).

Once you connect to the right repo connection in Eclipse RTC and chose the right project (`Configure Managed Projects`), you will see the repo workspace created on CLI.

You would still need to reload it though (overriding your local workspace), in order for Eclipse RTC to consider it "loaded".

Comment: Ok,thanks but My requirement was to enable the repository connection and get the sandbox ready for a group of users by the time they launch the eclipse for first time. To automate many such manual initial settings and configurations.

Comment: @CibiPCherian I don't remember a group of user being able to use the same repo workspace/local workspace (sandbox): those are attached to one owner only.

Comment: Sorry, please read it as 'for a user' . I intended to say that the solution will be used in a group.